# Is there a python implementation of websocket server over asyncore

Tags: python, websocket, asyncore

Is there a python implementation of websocket server over asyncore which supports all versions of Hixie and HyBi?

I have looked at results from Google like https://gist.github.com/719381, http://ldalab.ru/primer/websocket/websocket.py. They appear to support Hixie but not HyBi and its later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few websocket server implementations (http://autobahn.ws/, https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/txWS) based on [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/), an alternate asynchronous I/O and event-driven programming library for Python.

Comment: Is there any over asyncore? I will possibly have to write my own then taking parts from the above libs. The only problem would be to keep it updated with version changes :(

Comment: Use Twisted, man.  Don't pointlessly make your job more difficult.

Comment: asyncore doesnot have epoll support. Added to that the framework repeatedly loops through all the sockets checking for readability/writability before poll()ing. WTF? and its documentation says: "The module documented here solves many of the difficult problems for you, making the task of building sophisticated high-performance network servers and clients a snap." A clear mislead. Chose Twisted/Autobahn finally. Thanks Jean-Paul Calderone.